# Beamer from exam source

Tags: beamer, exam

I'm using the exam class to typeset exams and exercises. This is fine for paper exams, however, I'm looking for a solution to present those questions and answers via beamer.

The (in my opinion) "quick and dirty" solution is just to present the solution pdf.

Does anybody a better way know how to use the /question ... \begin{solution}...\end{solution} part in (probably many) beamer slides?

Here's a MWE:
The question:

```
\question
A vehicle has a mass of ...
\begin{parts}
\part[4]
 Find the maximum velocity!
 \begin{solutionorbox}[2.5cm]
   This is how you find out v_max.
 \end{solutionorbox}
\part[5] 
   Compute the accelleration time.
   \begin{solutionorbox}[1cm]
     \[ t = 20s \]
   \end{solutionorbox}
\end{parts}
```

And here comes the wrapper:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, addpoints, 11pt]{exam}

\printanswers

\newif\ifExamenisStyle
\ExamenisStylefalse

\usepackage{HGexam}

\begin{document}
\sloppy
\doctitle{Homework}{Physics}{\today}{Hermann}{}{}{}
\begin{questions}
  \input{beschlEnergieerhaltung}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Now I'd like one slide for the question and another one for each part. Hope anybody has a good suggestion.

Comment: We need more informations: example of your source and how do you want it in beamer (each solution follow exo in one frame? or in own frame? exos and then solotions?)

Comment: Beamer is a world unto itself.  I use \pdfscreen and \texpower instead.  See http://www.elfsoft2000.com/slides/irrational.pdf fore example.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find the HGexam package, so had to make a few changes.  If you use more than one font size, you may want to create a translation table (e.g. `\let\normalsize=\Large`)

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
%\usepackage{HGexam}% cannot find
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=4.5in,margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[display]{texpower}
\printanswers

\newif\ifExamenisStyle
\ExamenisStylefalse

\pagecolor{blue}
\color{white}

\begin{document}
\sloppy\Large
%\doctitle{Homework}{Physics}{\today}{Hermann}{}{}{}
\begin{questions}
\question
A vehicle has a mass of ...
\begin{parts}
\pause
\part[4]
 Find the maximum velocity!
\pause
 \begin{solutionorbox}[2.5cm]
   This is how you find out $v$\textsubscript{max}.
 \end{solutionorbox}
\pause
\part[5] 
   Compute the accelleration time.
  \pause
   \begin{solutionorbox}[1cm]
     \[ t = 20s \]
   \end{solutionorbox}
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```